# Assigning Session value to label in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, session, label, contentplaceholder

I have two masterpages. In the first master page i have a login.aspx page which opens a session["username"]. In the second masterpage i have a child masterpage linked to it.In the child masterpage i have a contentplaceholder  inside the contentplaceholder of the parent masterpage. I am able to assign session values to label everywhere except inside the contentplaceholder of the child masterpage. There are no errors but the label at run time is shown blank.I want the session["username"] value to be assigned to the label.

```
Label1.text=(string)session["username"] doesnt work.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually have a real value assigned to that location in Session?

Comment: yes the session stores the username when the user logs in and some pages can be only accessed when the user logs in.It worked,which means the session has a value. My doubt is that why i am not able to assign the session value to a label inside a contentplaceholder which is again inside another contentplaceholder.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to assign session values to label everywhere except inside the contentplaceholder of the child masterpage.

Ok, As you know `session` variable holds its value throughout the web appliation. So your session is working fine on different pages means that labels are showing values of `session["username"]`. If it is then you should have at the `variable(Label1.Text)` you are assigning values.

> Is this the right label? 
>   Is your label visible?

Comment: It is the right label..and yes it is visible. I can assign session value to a label in every page,n even the labels inside contentplaceholders too. I have a parentmasterpage and a childmasterpage.Inside the childmasterpage i have a contentplaceholder withing a contentplaceholder of the masterpage.My  problem is that i am not able to assign session value to the label inside the contentplaceholder which is inside the contentplaceholder of the masterpage.Hope you understand my question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Label1.Text= Session["username"] == null ? "Guest." : (string)Session["username"];
```

with this code you won't see blank label any more, it decides to show username (if exist) or "Guest." if `Session["username"]` is blank.

when the session is not filled it means that your assumption (that your session has value) is wrong and you need to take a close look at the code where your session gets value and see what's going wrong there.

Comment: But the page is inaccessible without the session. Only after logging in, i can visit the page. So that means the session has a value. I am able to assign the session value to a label in the masterpage1.i have a contentplaceholder1 in masterpage1 and i linked another masterpage2 with masterpage1. Inside the contentplaceholder1 in masterpage2 i added another contentplaceholder2 which has a label.And i want to assign the session value to that label. One important note is that the session has a value,otherwise i cant open the aspx pages under masterpage2,and it will redirect me to my login page.